# MySQL plug-in error when addFunctionView: RemoteRun[master] Can't recognize function: mysql::load

Tags: mysql, dolphindb

When I add a FunctionView by the function "addFunctionView", it report an error when the MySQL plugin calls the "load" function, as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When addFunctionView, the user-defined function will be persistently stored in the controller node, so in the cluster configuration file, besides the cluster.cfg that needs to be configured with preloadModules=plugins::mysql, the controller.cfg also needs to be configured with preloadModules=plugins::mysql.